# How to search for logs where "only certain fields exist" in Kibana?

Tags: logging, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, elk

I have multiple grok patterns configured to match the input in the Logstash config file. It starts detailed with multiple fields at the top and all encompassing just one {GREEDYDATA:message} at last. So some records might match just the last one or the one that has only certain fields. Is there a way to search for logs that have only "message" field, for example? I am able to search if certain fields exist in a record but not if only those fields exist.
Also, is having multiple grok patterns the best way to handle different kinds of logs?

I have around 100 fields so filtering with every thing else NOT EXISTS is not optimum.

Comment: Can you explain better what you are trying to do? In kibana you can query if a field exists on a document, but it won't tell if there are other fields in the document or not. You can however add a tag in that last grok to filter later on for documents that have this tag. Is something like this that you want?

Comment: yeah something similar. Didn't know about tags. I'll look into it. Thank you!

Comment: You can use the [add_tag](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-add_tag) option to add a tag to your document if the filter is successful, the value will be added into the field `tags`.